# MD5 for Git's git-credential-osxkeychain executable?

Tags: git, github, checksum

I'm setting up a GitHub account and have downloaded Git's credential-osxkeychain executable via the Password Caching section of [GitHub's instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git#password-caching). But... I am paranoid enough to look for some reassurance that I've got my hands on the right thing. Can anybody out there verify an MD5 for the executable at http://github-media-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/osx/git-credential-osxkeychain? ***(Yes, that is a direct link to the exe!)***  Better yet, point to an official source.

Comment: You're absolutely right to be cautious about this. I contacted GitHub's support about this issue and about the fact that the the source code for this utility should be open-sourced somewhere official (like GitHub's own GitHub organization). I encourage you to [do the same](https://github.com/contact).